# $B\bigcap(\bigcup_{n\in I} A_n)=\bigcup_{n\in I}\left(B \bigcap A_n\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Is the idea of this proof right? Am I missing anything?

Let $x \in B\bigcap(\bigcup_{n\in I} A_n)$, then $x \in B$ and $x \in \bigcup_{n\in I} A_n$. Then because $x\in B$, $x \in B \cap A_n$, thus $x \in \bigcup_{n\in I}\left(B \bigcap A_n\right)$.

Comment: You have only shown $B\cap(\bigcup_{n\in I} A_n)\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in I}(B\cap A_n)$. What about the other inclusion? (It's very similar, but it should be mentioned.)

Comment: I understand thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**: $x\in B$ and $x \in \bigcup_{n\in I} A_n$ implies $x\in B\cap A_n$ $\color{red}{for \space some \space n\in I}$

Then $x \in \bigcup_{n\in I}\left(B \bigcap A_n\right)$

**Second:**

$x \in \bigcup_{n\in I}\left(B \bigcap A_n\right)$ implies $x\in B\cap A_n$ for some $n\in I$ . Hence $x\in B$ and $x \in \bigcup_{n\in I} A_n$.Thus $x \in B\bigcap(\bigcup_{n\in I} A_n)$